# Windows 10 process sheduler changed? setting single process affinity for a single threaded game makes it lag horribly

Tags: windows

This wasnt happening before when i played around with it, so it seems it's due to an update in windows 10. Assigning single core affinity on a quad core to the game, makes even the title screen become massively laggy. 2 or 3 or 4 cores and it runs fine. The game pre-dates multi-core processors and is designed for single core, wolfenstein enemy territory.
Is there any documentation on this weird scheduler behaviour as part of updates? Unsuccessful in googling anything that directly relates.

As a side note, unlike in task manager, where setting single core affinity works, setting the compatibility shim SINGLEPROCAFFINITY actually becomes INSTALLER in `__COMPAT__` environment variable when you run the program and doesnt assign single core. I mention in passing as this might be related to how Microsoft is changing how scheduling works.

I haven't tested with anything else, as i'm confident this is due to Microsoft, instead of my endeavours. Unless it's a leftover from the time when i was testing and made a manifest xml file and installed it with mt utility, which i've since deleted, but may be hanging around in the innards of windows. I cant find any utility to investigate/remove an installed manifest.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at play here:

1) Just because you told 1 thread to use 1 processor... doesn't mean that everything else is told not to use that same processor.

2) Just because you *think* the game pre-dates multi-core processors that it cannot be multi-threaded, is just wrong.

I believe it is much more likely that you're running into GPU acceleration issues... (or the lack of support available to the game engine)  the id Tech 3 engine requires OpenGL support, and it's much-more likely that all of the OpenGL stuff is being emulated in software... and since the process is locked to a single CPU core, it's gonna suck.

I seriously doubt Microsoft's Scheduler is at fault in this case.

Comment: It worked fine before. Capable gpu with opengl support (Vega 64), which the game detects opengl support for. Game is fine with fps cap of 125 on 2 or 3 or 4 cores. 30 fps on 1 core, but even much more laggy than  displayed fps. When you switch between fullscreen and windowed, it takes one minute to switch. Only started recently and was never the case before. Unless it's caused by an AMD update that doesnt play nice with single core cpu being used. GPU is set to max all the time, as the green tech sux and causes stutter, because not much gpu is used. That's not relevant to issue though.

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of homework to do.  Again.  I seriously doubt it's the CPU scheduler in Windows.  If something like that was changed, it would affect nearly every cpu/time-sensitive program (game) that ever ran in Windows (both modern and old).  It would be VERY obvious if they made a change like that.

Comment: i'm not taking your "seriously doubt" seriously, as security updates and direct updates to scheduler code happens from time to time, as with any other part of the Windows OS codebase. In fact, there are many reddit etc posts about a scheduler update in 1903. What i'm lacking is detail about the specifics. I'm not interested in what this update did for Ryzen.